# Change relative img src's to absolute path's in javascript

Tags: javascript, filemaker

I am programming a sport-event-log database in Filemaker.

The webviewer contains a timer/clock that's written in Javascript.
The Filemaker webviewer needs Full absolute path's for all img src's so a had to change the relative path's into absolute.
That's not to difficult for the simple/single ones but for the function underneath for me it is rather difficult.

The function itself places the period/intermission signs (1st,2nd,3rd,-4th-) above the timer-digits.

The first part (for i loop) dims the signs. The second part sets the current period/intermission to bright (FULL) passed by the function parameter.
When I manually change the last calculated  `Lamp.src = Lamp.src.replace('Dim','Full');` into `Lamp.src = 'http://full path';` the sign appears on top again but then off course the function is not working.

```
// Show the current period/intermission sign in the display
function displayPeriode( pId ) {
   var i, idTab=['per1','pau1','per2','pau2','per3'];
   for ( i in idTab ) {
      try {
         var Lamp = document.getElementById(idTab[i]);
             Lamp.src = Lamp.src.replace('Full','Dim');
      } catch(e){};
   };
   try {
      Lamp = document.getElementById( pId );
      Lamp.src = Lamp.src.replace('Dim','Full');
   } catch(e){};
};
```

Can someone make this to work and please explain because I like to understand.

Comment: I am guessing, that by running src.replace you are changing to a different image file name. I do not see the reason why you can't rewrite the function for using the hardcoded paths

Comment: I am Javascript newbie, tried a lot of possibilities but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Show the current period/intermission sign in the display
function displayPeriode( pId ) {
   var i, idTab=['per1','pau1','per2','pau2','per3'];
   for ( i in idTab ) {
      try {
         var Lamp = document.getElementById(idTab[i]);
             Lamp.src = "http://full_path/Dim.jpg";
      } catch(e){};
   };

   try {
      Lamp = document.getElementById( pId );
      Lamp.src = "http://full_path/Full.jpg";
   } catch(e){};
};
```

Comment: This is working off course. I tried that to figure out how the function is working. But in this way I am loosing the variables (idTab[i]) and (pId) in the function and that's the difficulty.

Comment: The function I posted does not change how your variables are affected. How do you loose them? The problem is, that I can only see one function with no idea of the rest of the code. Try to post the link to the original JavaScript library